# Why autocomplete does not work inside of List view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I try to setup a very simple List view

```
import SwiftUI

struct DataModel : Identifiable {

var id: String {
    return title
}

var title : String
var subTitle : String
var expanded : Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {

let data : [DataModel] = [DataModel(title: "First Title", subTitle: "First Subtitle", expanded: false),
                          DataModel(title: "Second Title", subTitle: "Second Subtitle", expanded: false),
                          DataModel(title: "Third Title", subTitle: "Third Subtitle", expanded: false)]

var body: some View {
    List(data) {row in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(row.title)
                .font(.title)
            Text(row.subTitle)
                .font(.body)
        }
    }
 }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

So the question is: why autocomplete doesn't help me when I type 'row.' (inside of VStack view)? I see '_ self' only.

Comment: What is "Intellisense"? Are you working in a Microsoft program of some sort?

Comment: I think he meant autocomplete (control + space). I face the same issue sometimes, try: Product > Perform Action > Compile "[FILE NAME]" and see if that helps. Another reason might be because you have an error in your code.

Comment: @39fredy The code is very simple and pretty straightforward.  Of course, it runs and live preview is ok as well. 'Compile...' did not help.

Comment: Ok so this is not a Stack Overflow question. It’s a complaint to Apple. So send your complaint to Apple! File a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the autocomplete seems having a `level` limitation. You may help the editor do their job if you really need it.

```
   ....
   List(data) { (row : DataModel) in

    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
         row.****
     ....
```

Now the autocomplete will work inside the closure.

Comment: Thank you so much.
P.S. I don't understand, why this question downvoted...